# How much Amazon Machine can I run in a one-year free trial?

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance, aws-cli

I am interested in the question, I want to run several separate Amazon Machine Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS (HVM) and I can’t find information on how many can I run Amazon Machin to avoid blocking if I exceed the limit? How much Amazon Machine can I run in a one-year free trial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/free) you can run t2.micro for 750 hours each month. This time is **cumulative**. This means that you can run

- 1 x `t2.micro` instance for 750 hours per month, or
- 2 x `t2.micro` instances concurrently for 375 hours per month, or
- 4 x `t2.micro` instances for 187.5 hours per month (about 1 week).

So if you run multiple instances a month, their time adds up. If the total time is greater then 750 hours, then you will be charge.